# How to get a sublist view of elements *not* inside the given index range

Tags: java

I want to sweep over a list of files and in each step get just a *validation* subset and a *training* subset.

In Java I can use `List#sublist(int from, int to)` in order to get a sublist but is is there a nice and easy way to get all elements **except** those in that range? E.g.

```
List<File> valid = this.sampleFiles.subList(fromIndex, toIndex);
List<File> train = this.sampleFiles.notInSubList(fromIndex, toIndex);
```

Comment: How about `this.sampleFiles.removeAll(this.sampleFiles.subList(fromIndex, toIndex));` ?

Comment: @911DidBush Not really an option. This ends in a concurrent exception.

Comment: for an arraylist, you might create a new ArrayList(this.sampleFiles) and then use ArrayList.removeRange(from, to)

Comment: @911DidBush An that would not be a view.

Comment: Do you really need a *view* Otherwise just get and merge two sublists.

Comment: @lexicore It does not have to be a view but those lists are getting passed to a callback function for further processing.

Comment: is there a function to derive those indexes? or how do you decide, which entries are valid and which are not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the [Stream API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) and [Collectors.partitioningBy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html) could help you. That way you get a map with the partitions as you wish them to be.

```
sampleFiles.stream()
           .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(/* your partition function */);
```

In the above example you would gain a `Map<Boolean, List<File>>`. But also other partitions are possible. Maybe `IntStream.range` would also work.

If you don't like streams, the following may also work...

```
List<String> sampleFiles = ...
List<String> valid = sampleFiles.subList(fromIndex, toIndex);
List<String> train = new ArrayList(sampleFiles);
train.removeAll(valid);
```

I don't think there is an easier way to get the remainder of a list, beside those variants.

Comment: I went for the second solution this time (although I like streams) - I didn't realize that I have to create a new `ArrayList` for 'train`. I was always getting a concurrent modification exception. Thanks for helping out!